# How can I use a google classroom API on a website I am making to access specific rosters and put them on a list displayed on the website?

Tags: python, api, google-classroom

I am making a website for a teacher and he wants to be able to take attendance easily and he wants me to use the google classroom api to access his roster in his class so that it can then display that list of names on the website and he can easily take attendance there

Answer (score 4):

Roster importing is a common use case we see with the [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/). Here's what the workflow typically looks like:

1. On your website, the teacher chooses the option to import a Classroom [Course](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses).
2. On your backend, call the [courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) method through the Classroom API, which will return a json response.
3. From this json response, list the titles of the teacher's courses for them to select 1. Note: you'll need to keep track of the course IDs to continue onto the next step.
4. With the course ID, call the [students.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list) method and display all names on your website for teachers to take attendance.

On each of the links above, you can use the API Explorer to see exactly how these methods behave. I also recommend you check the documentation for managing [courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses) and [students/teachers](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users) -- there are code snippets for a few different languages, including Python.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was wondering when I looked at Classroom API I saw that you needed a G Suite account and that was one of the reasons I wasn't able to work it cause I am not an institution (you need to be one to create an account) and I was wondering if the method you described requires me to have an account. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, you will need a G Suite account (either consumer or enterprise) to use the Classroom API.

Comment: @lesley2958 Is it possible to do this flow on the front end, or do I have to do it from my server? Ideally, I would like to perform these steps on the front end to not require any back and forth between my client and server

Comment: @lesley2958 The tokens are stored in a pickle file on the server. So if I host my website, and enable login for google credentials for everyone visiting my website, won't the tokens.pkl be created for each and every person logging in to the server?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to start with is to navigate in the official documentation for [Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started).

> The Classroom API provides a RESTful interface for you to manage
>   courses and rosters in Google Classroom.

For python, you can refer to the quickstart guide designed for [Python implementation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/python). See [sample code](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

To access students, use [REST Resource: courses.students](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students).

You will be able to use the supported methods such as [**`create`**](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/create), [**`delete`**](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/delete), [**`get`**](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/get) and [**`list`**](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list).

Comment: I looked at the Python implementation and it asks for a G Suite Account but in order to create one I need to sign up as an institution. Since I am not wanting to do that, is there another way to do it without that account?